# trying to simulate a soocer game shootout using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have to create a game of 5 rounds simulating a soccer shootout using a 2x3 array that represents the goal. The computer randomly picks 3 places to block and the user chooses one place to shoot. If the user chooses a coordinate that is not blocked then its a goal. Two functions are needed, one where the computer picks 3 random places to block and the other function is prints out the goal every round. If the user scores 3 times then they win, otherwise they lose.

The output should look like this(B=Blocked, G=Goal, "-" = empty space):

B - B

B - G

Ive been stuck on my code and have gotten an error that I just cant seem to fix within both functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void computerPick(char soccer[]);
void shot(char shooter[]);


int main()
{
int userInputX;
int userInputY;

srand(time(NULL));

char soccer[2][3];
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        soccer[i][j]='-';

    }

}

cout<<"Pick a X coordinate to shoot at: "<<endl;
cin>>userInputX;
cout<<"Pick a Y coordinate to shoot at: "<<endl;
cin>>userInputY;

computerPick(soccer);
shot(soccer,userInputY,userInputX);

}
void computerPick(char soccer[])
{

int x = rand()%3;
int y = rand()%2;

soccer[x][y]='B';

}

void shot(char shooter[], int userInputY, int userInputX)
{

int score=0;

if(shooter[userInputX][userInputY]!='B')
    cout<<"shot is good"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"shot is blocked"<<endl;



}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to include more details on the error you are encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use correct types for arguments and have to match the prototype declaration and definition of functions.

This code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void computerPick(char soccer[][3]);
void shot(char shooter[][3], int userInputY, int userInputX);


int main()
{
    int userInputX;
    int userInputY;

    srand(time(NULL));

    char soccer[2][3];
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            soccer[i][j]='-';

        }

    }

    cout<<"Pick a X coordinate to shoot at: "<<endl;
    cin>>userInputX;
    cout<<"Pick a Y coordinate to shoot at: "<<endl;
    cin>>userInputY;

    computerPick(soccer);
    shot(soccer,userInputY,userInputX);

}
void computerPick(char soccer[][3])
{

    int x = rand()%3;
    int y = rand()%2;

    soccer[x][y]='B';

}

void shot(char shooter[][3], int userInputY, int userInputX)
{

    int score=0;

    if(shooter[userInputX][userInputY]!='B')
        cout<<"shot is good"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"shot is blocked"<<endl;



}
```

Comment: where should i put the for loop so i can make it go through 5 times because the game is 5 rounds

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at these parts again:

```
char soccer[2][3];
```

and

```
int x = rand()%3;
int y = rand()%2;

soccer[x][y]='B';
```

Also note that booleans would be clearer in your two dimensional array instead of chars of 'B' or 'G'.
Also when using multidimensional arrays as parameters, you can pass them as

```
int foo(int (*array)[5][10])
```

Which means that you are passing a pointer to an array of fixed size 5-10